# Hyperledger Explorer Login page Disabling

Tags: authentication, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-explorer

In the latest version of hyperledger explorer. They have added a login page.
[image]
I want to remove that and keep my explorer public to the people. There is an option in

> blockchain-explorer/app/platform/fabric/config.json

The document says that there is an option enableAuthentication that you can make false and that will remove the login page but Even after adding that option nothing happens. I am still getting the login page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the option in your connection profile (e.g. [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer/blob/864b622a7b7782c540fa68ef63f85bec63d50cd0/app/platform/fabric/connection-profile/first-network.json#L16)).

```
{
    name: "first-network",
    version: "1.0.0",
    license: "Apache-2.0",
    client: {
        tlsEnable: true,
        enableAuthentication: false,
```